# laravel run failed job locally instead of pushing it back on the queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue

Is it possible to run a failed job from the failed_jobs table locally for debugging?

I only found `php artisan queue:retry` in the docs, but this pushes the job back on the queue instead of executing it.

I would like to directly run the failed job instead.

Comment: I would argue failed jobs is not for debugging but for information about what's failed. Often you base your jobs on data from models, wouldn't that be able to recreate it?

Comment: Yes, I could also manually get the job name and parameters from the payload column, but it would be a lot more convenient to just state a row id and run that job.

Comment: php artisan queue:retry and changing you local environment to sync actually do that ?

Comment: Changing the queue driver to sync did not change anything.Still says: The failed job [1] has been pushed back onto the queue!

Comment: There is a queue field on failed jobs table, can you change that to sync? and would that help. I'm thinking there is a way to make this work.

Comment: Then it just added it back to the jobs table with the queue column value sync

Comment: However, this allows me to just define a unique queue name and then I can locally run a queue worker for this queue. I'll post the code as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your FailedJobs Model:

```
public function retry() {
        $this->queue = 'failed_jobs_'.$this->id;
        $this->save();
        Artisan::call('queue:retry '.$this->id);
        Artisan::call('queue:work --once --queue='.$this->queue);
    }
```

And then run/debug the job locally like this:

```
    FailedJob::find($id)->retry();
```